# Wrong variable in for...loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Not a great title I know but I'm not sure how to word it. Anyway, in brief I am trying to calculate the number of scores, the total of scores and the average and grade of the scores. I am using for... loops to complete this task. So...
my function prototypes:

```
int validateNumber(int);
void summary(int,int,float,char);
char getGrade(float);
float getAvg(int,int);
```

probably only the validateNumber(int) is relevant here but just in case.

The main()

```
int num, total, scores;
cout << over4 << "How many scores do you want to average? " << endl; 
cout << over4 << "Enter a value from 1 to 4: ";
cin >> num;
```

And the calls(?):

```
total = validateNumber(num);
summary(num,total,average,grade);
```

And then the definitions:

```
int validateNumber(int num)
{
int total = 0, score;

    while (num < 1 || num > 4)
    {
        cout << over3 << num << " is not between 1 and 4! Try again: "; 
        cin >> num;
    }
system("CLS");

for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{   
cout << over3 << "Enter score " << i << ": " << endl;
cout << over3 << "Enter a value from 0 to 100: ";
cin >> score;       
    while (score < 0 || score > 100)
    {
        cout << over3 << score << " is not between 0 and 100! Renter the score: "
             << i << ": ";  
        cin >> score;
    }
       total += score;
}
return total;
}
```

and:

```
void summary(int num,int total,float average,char grade)
{
    cout << over4 << "Number of scores : " << num << endl;
    cout << over4 << "Scores total     : " << total << endl;
    cout << over4 << "Average          : " << average << "%" << endl;
    cout << over4 << "Grade            : " << grade << endl;
    cout << down11;
}
```

When the user enters a num value between 1 and 4, there is no problem, the program works as it should. However when the user enters a value for num not in that range, the function works as it should BUT the summary will tell me that the number of scores was that first erroneous value and as a result mess up my average/grade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your function you are passing by value not by reference, so the change which is done in your function `int validateNumber(int);` is only in that function's scope, outside num's value is same as it was first. you should send value by reference. in this way :

```
int validateNumber(int &);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you pass num to the validateNumber function by value. The local num in the validateNumber function copies the global num's value and get's processed accordingly. However, the global num variable stays as it were. In order to change the num itself you will have to pass it by reference.  Change the parameters on your function definition to: `int validateNumber(int &num) { ... }`

Comment: So i put an & sign in front of the int? That just gives me an error... I have yet to learn this in my class as well...

Comment: After the int not in front.

Comment: No; you put the `&` after `int` and before `num`, as shown in the code fragment.

Comment: Sorry that is what I what i meant... that gives me an eroor

Comment: it says i am an idiot... I wasnt adding the & to the function prototype definition. Oh well that works! thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.

Comment: Just wondering so I can improve my future answers, was there something you didn't like about the answer?